# opennlp change eos char

Tags: java, split, opennlp, sentence

I'd like to change the end-of-sentence separator in my openNlp SentenceDetectorME. I'm using opennlp 1.5.3.
Since the normal version detects only the phrases separated by '.', my purpose is to add other sentence separator like ';', '!' and '?', passing the char array eos[] to a SentenceDetectorFactory. I read that you must use the .train method SentenceDetectorME, but I don't understand how because it is static and requires a train model. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.*;

public class SenTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String paragraph = "12oz bottle poured into a tulip. Pleasing aromas of citrus rind, lemongrass, peaches, and toasted caramel are picked up from the start. After it settles a bit, more of a fresh baked bread crust and tangerine comes through, and even later, the bread crust turns more towards a blackened pizza crust. It pours a slightly hazy copper-orange color with a creamy white head that retains well; it leaves a thick puffy ring with a creamy island and a decent, messy lace along the glass. Great balance between medium high levels of sweet and bitter. The texture is creamy on the palate with a body towards the higher end of medium. The carbonation is a touch effervescent or fizzy, but overall, soft. There’s a very pronounced grapefruit tartness up front, but it mellows quickly after the first few sips. It finishes with a zesty combination of lemongrass, caramel, and stonefruit. The aftertaste is primarily sweet, overripe tangerines and it’s peel with a tart grapefruit bitter lingering in the mouth. Overall very refreshing, straddles the line between IPA and APA.";
    char eos[] = {';', '.', '!', '?' };
    int counter = 0;
    // always start with a model, a model is learned from training data

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream( System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "/lib/en-sent.bin" );
    SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel( is );
    SentenceDetectorME sdetector = new SentenceDetectorME( model );


    String sentences[] = sdetector.sentDetect( paragraph );

    for ( String s : sentences ) {

        counter++;
        System.out.println( "Frase numero " + counter + ": " + s );
    }
    is.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how training works.

You will need to provide a large selection of sentences / paragraphs which contain the characters you wish to detect (! ;) etc. This is because opennlp will detect features within the sentence to determine if its a true sentence split, or just a punctuation insertion for other reasons.

Take for example the following example:

Helen was thirty ;;years;; old; she was actually young!

in this line the ;;years;; is simply some markup, and should not be detected as a sentence split. (the more occurances where ;; appears will determine if it is a sentence split)

In your example, you may as well just use a string.split() and split based on the inputted eos, but this means you will split the sentence above also on ;; pattern as well.